# Spark dataframe: Schema for type Unit is not supported

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am using Spark 1.5.0 and I have this issue:

```
val df = paired_rdd.reduceByKey { 
    case (val1, val2) => val1 + "|" + val2 
}.toDF("user_id","description")
```

Here is sample data for df, as you can see the column description has
this format `(text1#text3#weight | text1#text3#weight|....)`

user1

> book1#author1#0.07841217886795074|tool1#desc1#0.27044260397331488|song1#album1#-0.052661673730870676|item1#category1#-0.005683148395350108

I want to sort this df based on weight in descending order here is what I tried:

First split the contents at "|" and then for each of those strings, split them at "#" and get the 3rd string which is weight and then convert that into a double value

```
val getSplitAtWeight = udf((str: String) => { 
    str.split("|").foreach(_.split("#")(2).toDouble)
})
```

Sort based on the weigh value returned by the udf (in descending manner)

```
val df_sorted = df.sort(getSplitAtWeight(col("description")).desc)
```

I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException:
>   Schema for type Unit is not supported at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:153)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:29)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$class.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:64)
>   at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.ScalaReflection$.schemaFor(ScalaReflection.scala:29)
>   at org.apache.spark.sql.functions$.udf(functions.scala:2242)

Answer (score 2):

Change `foreach` in your `udf` to `map` as following will eliminate the exception:

```
def getSplitAtWeight = udf((str: String) => { 
    str.split('|').map(_.split('#')(2).toDouble)
})
```

The problem with your method is that `foreach` method on `List` doesn't return anything, i.e., its result is of type `Unit` that's why you get the `Exception`. To understand more about the `foreach`, check [this blog](http://Note%20that%20this%20is%20a%20relatively%20common%20way%20to%20use%20the%20foreach%20method.%20Because%20foreach%20takes%20a%20procedure%20that%20doesn%E2%80%99t%20return%20anything,%20and%20because%20the%20result%20of%20foreach%20is%20also%20Unit,%20the%20foreach%20method%20is%20typically%20used%20for%20its%20side%20effects%20--%20something%20like%20this%20example%20where%20output%20is%20printed%20for%20a%20user%20to%20see.).

Comment: I now get this error: Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'UDF(annotation) DESC' due to data type mismatch: cannot sort data type array<double>;
 at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.package$AnalysisErrorAt.failAnalysis(package.scala:42)

Comment: Not exactly sure. On spark 1.6.0, there is no exception. But I think what it means is that for every string in the description after splitting, you get four numbers which is where the `array<double>` comes from. And spark doesn't know how to sort columns which contains arrays as element. And also which number you are going to sort by is also a good question to ask before proceeding.